# Problem with edges over text when using "edge from parent fork down"

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

I am using tikz to depict a decision tree, but something is going wrong: some lines are being plotted above the text (see picture below)

[image]

This is the code I am using:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
    level distance = 3cm,
    sibling distance = 4.5cm,
    every node/.append style = {draw},
    edge from parent fork down
]
\node{\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 33.8\% & 1510\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 66.2\% & 2957 \end{tabular}}
    % Node 1
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 13.9\% & 78\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 86.1\% & 482 \end{tabular}} edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\leq 28.360$}}
    % Node 2
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 5.6\% & 16\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 94.4\% & 268 \end{tabular}} edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(28.360,28.510]$}}
    % Node 3
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 17.5\% & 244\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 82.5\% & 1150 \end{tabular}}
        % Node 8
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 15.1\% & 43\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 84.9\% & 241 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\leq 20.780$}}
        % Node 9
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 24.4\% & 68\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 75.6\% & 211 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(20.780,21.170]$}}
        % Node 10
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 16.0\% & 133\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 84\% & 698 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$>21.170$}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(28.510,32.490]$}
    }
    % Node 4
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 27.5\% & 155\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 72.5\% & 408 \end{tabular}} edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(32.490,37.290]$}}
    % Node 5
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 41.6\% & 116\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 58.4\% & 163 \end{tabular}} edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(37.290,40.010]$}}
    % Node 6
    child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 57.8\% & 480\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 42.2\% & 350 \end{tabular}}
        % Node 11
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 41.9\% & 116\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 58.1\% & 161 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\leq 27.710$}}
        % Node 12
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 58.3\% & 161\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 41.7\% & 115 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(27.710,28.620]$}}
        % Node 13
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 73.3\% & 203\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 26.7\% & 74 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$>28.620$}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\in(40.010,50.640]$}
    }
    % Node 7
    child {node [right=4.8cm] {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 75.6\% & 421\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 24.4\% & 136 \end{tabular}}
        % Node 14
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 67.4\% & 188\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 32.6\% & 91 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$\leq 28.380$}}
        % Node 15
        child {node {\begin{tabular}{lll} {\footnotesize\color{blue}$\blacklozenge$}\,Large & 83.8\% & 233\\{\footnotesize\color{red}$\blacklozenge$}\,Small & 16.2\% & 45 \end{tabular}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$> 28.380$}}
        edge from parent node [fill=white,draw=none] {$>50.640$}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Fabio

Comment: The lines and nodes are drawn in the same order as the children. The edges from the siblings on the right will draw over the edges (and nodes) of the siblings on the left. The solution is probably to draw the edges and only save a `coordinate` along its path and place the nodes later. You might want to look into the `forest` ([tag:forest]) package or the `graphs` and `graphdrawing` libraries from TikZ for a more uptodate way to draw trees with TikZ.

Comment: Would you be interested by a direct solution, one which doesn't use the library `trees`?